# How should we promote this site on our personal weblogs?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I know that Area 51 has ads for promoting proposals, e.g.:

[Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Buddhism http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/45110.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism?referrer=wfrtzfRZknfyJ6AWfccLUw2)

```
<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism?referrer=wfrtzfRZknfyJ6AWfccLUw2">
    <img src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/45110.png" width="220" height="250" alt="Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Buddhism" />
</a>
```

but I don't see anywhere that they offer ads for the betas themselves. Should we create one, or is there a standard, accepted way for displaying such a link on your site? Or should we just use the Area 51 ad?

Edit: another tool that SE offers, maybe not terribly appropriate for self-effacing Buddhists, is flair, e.g.:

[image: profile for yuttadhammo at Buddhism Stack Exchange, Q&A for people practicing or interested in Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice]

which can be placed on one's website or weblog.

Comment: SE indeed does not create any extra ads for beta sites. I'm sure there are some people here that are good with graphics that can whip up something that looks nice, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dynamic image as an example of what can be easily accomplished with PHP; the number of days on this image will be created dynamically, based on the date:

[image: Q&A Dynamic Logo]

I've not quite got an exact time when our beta started, so it's still a little off.

Comment: Per [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110?phase=beta) (hover the thing below "private beta start"), the site launched at 19:00 UTC on June 17, 2014.